# How to create Google Rich Snippets?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, rich-snippets

As the title says how to create link like this

[image: a Rich Snippet on Google Search, showing the rating and the price of an Android app]

I see many companies doing this, and ThemeForest also sells WordPress themes that allow you to create Rich Snippets.

I wanna know how to create it? And is there any plugin which can help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add structured data to your documents.

You can either do this by hand, by using services like Google’s [Structured Data Markup Helper](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3069489?hl=en), or by using CMS/themes/plugins - the only thing that matters is the result, i.e., that your documents contain the structured data which you want to convey about your content.

Google recognizes (some parts of) the vocabulary **Schema.org**, and they support the **JSON-LD**, **Microdata** and/or **RDFa** syntax for this purpose.

You can find the Rich Snippets documentation on https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/.

For example, if you want a [Rich Snippet for your software app](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/sw-app), you have to use the [`SoftwareApplication` type](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) (or one of its sub-types) and add the [`name` property](http://schema.org/name) as well as at least two of the properties [`aggregateRating`](http://schema.org/aggregateRating), [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers), [`operatingSystem`](http://schema.org/operatingSystem), and [`applicationCategory`](http://schema.org/applicationCategory).